# What is the effect of supernatural blood on Kindred?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

In the core rulebook, it is mentioned in passing that the blood of Werewolves and Elder Kindred is more potent than that of humans or animals. There is no mention of taking blood from other supernaturals.

Is there a reference to the exact effect of the blood of Elders, Garou, Demons and the like on Kindred?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Puppy Blood

According to Revised Edition, page 278, in the **"Dangerous Draughts"** sidebar, Lupine blood has a 2:1 ratio; for every point of lupine blood drunk from the werewolf, you get 2.  (The sidebar makes the ratio 25:10, but later examples imply this is rounded down).  Additionally, the Kindred is at +1 difficulty to resist frenzy for each point remaining in the kindred's system.

Drink 1 point by volume, and you have 2 points to use, and 2 points to work off before your frenzy resistance is back to normal.

## Fae Blood

No hard rules are given for Fae blood, but the text implies that it might be either very blissful to drink, or tortuously painful.

## Wraiths, Risen

Wraiths don't have bodies, so no blood.  Risen have embalming fluid, yuck.

## Mages

Simple mortals, according to VtM Revised.

Comment: I would like to add to this answer, but I don't know if it's ok to directly edit.

Dark Ages: Fae set the effect of drinking fae blood (still, these fae are different to modern changelings). The exact effect depends on the court:

* Summer: +2 dices fire and sunlight soaking, but the vampire emits light that hurt other vampires (1 lethal level)
* Spring: +1 charisma but +1 difficulty to frenzy rolls.
* Autumn: Hear thoughts (as Auspex 4) but can be confused with multiple thoughts.
* Winter: +1 to a Physical Attribute, but new blood gives half of the blood points.

Comment: I seem to remember Fae blood being described by potentially madenning. I can't recall where. However, as for mages - I'll have to dig out the quote but the text in Revised does say that some are sufficiently *strange* and unnatural that their very blood is changed and unsuitable for drinking. Whether that change is an active on part of the mage (transforming themselves) or perhaps due to resonance or even Paradox, wasn't specified.

Comment: Good info here! For the question of fairies, here's a question which has some good answers on the specific effects of a kindred drinking specifically fae blood: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/145100/what-are-the-potential-side-effects-on-a-kindred-from-drinking-fae-blood

Answer (score 5):

I've found official information only regarding Garou and a "psychic" humans (which can relate easily to Mages) in the [Vampire:The Masquerade Player's guide 2nd Edition (page 89)](https://i.yuki.la/tg/1396724213021.pdf)

**Lupine Blood**

> Like the blood of psychics, the vitae taken from werewolves
>   has an unusual and troublesome effect on the Kindred.
>   Ingesting the blood of a werewolf can provoke a frenzy in
>   the unwary Cainite. 
>   For every Blood Point of Lupine blood a vampire has in her
>   system, the difficulty level of any rolls to avoid a frenzy
>   increases by one. Thus a Cainite who has drunk deeply
>   from a werewolf is so hyped that she is constantly on the
>   verge of frenzy. This is not a pleasant situation for the
>   unfortunate vampire. Even if she avoids frenzy she will find herself on
>   edge and rather paranoid until the blood is out of her
>   system. 
>   Rumors also abound that drinking from werewolves can
>   temporarily grant levels of Celerity or Potence. This is not
>   always the case; it is a factor of the Lupine's Pure Breed
>   Background. The more pure the werewolf's lineage, the
>   more power it gives a bloodsucker. There are tales of a few
>   insane Kindred deliberately hunting Pure-bred Lupines for
>   their vitae

**Mortals with Psychic Powers**

> The blood of a mortal with psychic abilities can have a very
>   unsettling effect upon a Kindred who ingests it. The human
>   has had years of experience in controlling her psychic
>   ability, and has often partaken of a regimen of training,
>   discipline, and hard work. The same cannot be said for the
>   poor vampire. While the vitae ingested from the psychic
>   individual is in the vampire's system, she may be subject to
>   uncontrolled manifestations of the power. For instance, if
>   the blood of a telekinetic has been ingested, the vampire
>   may unwittingly cause objects to be hurled about the
>   vicinity. This is distracting, to say the least.
>  The Storyteller
>   will decide the exact manifestation.

Now, I wasn't able to find official information about the rest supernaturals, the general rule seems to be "By drinking blood of X you become bit like X " (by drinking blood of human you look more human etc). Following that we can extend a bit homebrew rules for other supernaturals: in example blood of Changelings should induce form of madness etc.

Answer (score 3):

Elders' blood differs as blood of dissimilar creatures, humans, clans, vampires. **It is more concentrated and strong comparing to weaker vampires.** See the citation beneath. This applies to the most of supernaturals.

Some particular elders and elders of some clans as whole have special properties in their blood for kindreds' taste and mages, but I didn't resemble any common qualities among all elders (except more blood points in the same volume and other issues for any vampire's blood as the blood-bonds).

*Elders. From the 3rd Edition (revised).*

> Remember that elder vampires concentrate their blood - while the
>   volume of blood in their bodies is no greater than any other
>   vampire's, each pint of blood is worth more than one point.

*Garou*

> ~20-25 bp per creature, more concentrated than human's. +1 resist the
>   beast rolls for each digested blood point. Also, werewolf won't die
>   from blood loss even with only 1 bp. Pure breeds' blood gives celerity
>   and potence points to the vampire.

*Daemons. Nothing in the corebook, something from wiki, but I can't verify that this is from the official books. I haven't that books (Demonic Investment, MTSC: Infernalism: The Path of Screams, p. 73 –76 Storytellers Handbook to the Sabbat The Book of Madness).*

> Demons cannot be blood bonded nor can one be bonded to a demon. To
>   drink from a demon's blood provides no nourishment to a vampire and
>   will either give an extremely pleasure rush or make one very sick. If
>   a vampire repeatedly shares blood with a demon, one of the devil's
>   marks will appear on them.

Comment: Is it referenced anywhere what the blood of other kinds of supernaturals, such as Garou and Demons, has?

Comment: @Wraithguard Garou are werewolves as I resemble, why did you separate their cases? Werewolves' blood effects for Kindred briefly described in core book.

Comment: @Wraithguard Daemons are vastly different creatures, they even can be liquidless. Sorry, I was DMing VtM far ago, also that books weren't mine. There were some explanations about this in "Demonic Investment. " I added this to the answer, but I can't verify that this is from the official books. Definitely, nothing about this in the corebook.

Answer (score 0):

Going with 20th Anniversary edition, non-mortals have "more potent blood".  Where the average mortal has 10 blood points, werewolves have 20, vampires have their blood pool max (which varies of course by generation).  The only mechanical affect I can see other than diablerie for kindred is that when you drink more powerful creatures, you get more than one blood point in a single "sip". (page 269-270)

Comment: Is it referenced anywhere what the blood of other kinds of supernaturals, such as Garou and Demons, has?

Comment: @Wraithguard Garou are mentioned in the post.